# How do we know that information added to a blockchain is true?

Tags: blockchain, verification

Let's say there existed a blockchain that recorded the history of a rental real estate property. If I wanted to add a review of my experience living in that property, how would the blockchain verify that the review is genuine? Let's assume that any review coming from a person who really lived there, or who really visited there is genuine. What we want to avoid is someone who has not lived there or who had not visited leaving a review that is permanently added to the blockchain.

My guess is nodes of the blockchain who are attempting to verify the review would connect to databases that would have information on whether a person lived or visited the property. But I may also be missing how blockchain works altogether.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Given your example of a blockchain used for rental property use, I would assume that each transaction on the blockchain records who is currently renting the property. Using Alice and Bob as example names, let's say Alice is the current renter but her rental agreement has expired. If Bob wants to rent the place next, Alice would first transfer ownership back to the landlord, and from there the landlord would transfer ownership to Bob. On the blockchain, it would look something like this:

**Alice** transfers ownership to **Landlord**

**Landlord** transfers ownership to **Bob**

Now, let say Bob wants to leave a review later on. How can we verify that Bob has been a previous renter? Well, it's simple. All we would need to do is go back through the blockchain's history and check that rental ownership has been transferred to Bob at some point, which in this case it has. The blockchain *is* the database. Anyone who has had their names previously written down on the blockchain may leave a review.

EDIT

To answer your question in the comments, how do we know that the transaction `Alice transfers ownership to Landlord` is true? Well, this transaction is considered valid if we can verify that Alice was the one to submit it. But how does this work?

Alice would have been given a private key and a public key when setting up an address for the blockchain. You can think of the public key as a unique identifier for her, which in this case is just “Alice” since there’s no other Alice’s in this example. The private key is like a password: you need it in order to access your account and submit valid transactions to the blockchain.

In order for Alice to submit a valid transaction in her name, she would have to digitally sign it using her private key. There’s signing function that looks like this:

```
Sign(transaction, private key) = Signature
```

Given a transaction, Alice can use her private key to “sign it” and produce a signature that’s sent to the miner. When the miner gets this transaction along with the signature, they can verify using a second function:

```
Verify(transaction, Signature, public key) = True/False
```

Using this function, the miner can verify if the transaction WAS in fact made with the private key associated with the public key. If it was, it’s a valid transaction and can be added to the blockchain.

I don’t know the math behind these functions because it’s quite complicated, so unfortunately I can’t explain in detail here.

I recommend watching [3Blue1Brown’s video on Bitcoin](https://youtu.be/bBC-nXj3Ng4), which goes over digital signing. It’s a long video but it goes over all of the basics of understanding blockchain in an easy to understand way.

EDIT 2

In your second follow up question, there would have to be a rule coded into the blockchain that the Landlord cannot rent out the property to anyone else while there is a current renter. In this case, if the Landlord tries to submit this transaction while Alice is renting:

**Landlord** transfers ownership to **Bob**

the validator would go back in the blockchain's history and check that the last renter has transferred ownership back to the Landlord, which in this case is not true. The blockchain would still have Alice recorded down as the current renter, and so this transaction would be considered invalid. Since Alice is the only with the private key to her account, she's the *only* one that can transfer ownership back to the Landlord so it can be rented again.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. That makes sense.

Comment: Another piece of the puzzle for me is to understand how the information that is to be added to the blockchain is known to be true, even by the miner. 

So, say a miner has good intentions and does the proof of work to get a piece of information to the blockchain. For example, that Alice is transferring ownership to the Landlord. How does the miner know that this piece of information is indeed true and worth investing the computational power to have a chance to get it added?

Comment: @Paris I’ve updated my answer with your question above. Hopefully it helps. If this answer was useful/answers your original question, generally the stack overflow procedure is to upvote/accept the answer ;)

Comment: Jasper, thank you. That's clear. 

A follow up on that. Let's say the Landlord is malicious and submits information to the blockchain that he is transferring ownership to another person, which Alice would not be happy about because she still lives there and has ownership. Would Alice (or all the participants in that blockchain account) also need to verify that the information being submitted is true? I know I keep digging but I keep finding places where there could be a breakdown in the validity of the information.

Comment: Also, I'm new to this so can't upvote yet but I've accepted your answer (my first one ;))

Comment: @Paris no worries. I've updated my answer once again to respond to your other follow up question.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update. That solves another piece of the puzzle. So, there needs to be an exhaustive set of rules coded into the blockchain? So that it can be referenced to verify valid inputs. Also, do all the participants need to agree to these rules, like a terms of use for the blockchain? And who writes the rules - the creator of a given  blockchain instance?
Thanks again Jasper.

Comment: Yes, depending on what the blockchain is used for it'll have it's own set of rules coded in by the developer. It's up to the developer to decide how to verify the transaction. There's no terms of use per se, rather anyone who does not agree with the rules set by a particular blockchain does not have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your ideology is somewhat correct .There’s sth in block chain called proof of work … responsible for validation of a block on the chain before it’s added since it’s like a mathematical puzzle including verification of whether the person stayed or not can be a factor of the algorithm